# How to share file or folder using ios Api?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, dropbox-api

I have following question in my mind and i want help regarding that
- Is it posable to share file and folder using Dropbox Ios API
- Is it posable to get Share Dropbox URL of any file or folder therefore share with others by sending email etc.

I have application which is using Dropbox and i want to share any file or folder with my friends? how could i do that , how could i inform my friends to get that perticular file from my share folder on. i think for this i need shared file URL to send to friend so they download file on this path`?
is that all posable , if yes! then how , which method or class of dropbox ios api?

Thanks alot .

Comment: Did you even check the API documentation? It's there.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares

Comment: yes,i have checked the link https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares. but can't find any specific Api calls and methods for  file or folder sharing.

Comment: The shares method is what you want. It gives you a URL for a file so that you can share it with others.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `loadSharableLinkForFile` in `DBRestClient`.  The full documentation is on the website: http://dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable reply.But i didn't find any specific Api calls for file sharing in DropBox in http://dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares.

Comment: The Dropbox API currently doesn't allow manipulating Dropbox Shared Folders.  However, the `/shares` call might allow you to do what you need.  It creates a URL to a file/folder in your Dropbox that you can give to others (anyone with the URL has read-only access to the file/folder).

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox API doesn't implement any method that allow you to share a folder.
It's a limitation.
You can share a folder only in the website.

Comment: I dont think thats true `loadSharableLinkForFile` should do the trick

Comment: I'm talking about FOLDER, not FILE... what you mentioned is a method that give you an URL to download a file. This is completely different from "sharing folder with other user"

Comment: Oh you mean like you share on dropbox's website enter email address and invite others to folder? If thats rights sorry but OP asks  Is  `Share Dropbox URL of any file or folder therefore share with others by sending email ` thats why I commented to your answer